# How to disable hover decoration in Flutter TabBar

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Description]

I want to disable that gray box that is shown when the mouse is over the tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `overlayColor` property to change hover color. For your case,

```dart
bottom: TabBar(
  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
```

More about [overlayColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar/overlayColor.html).